# How to sort RDD entries using two features simultaneously?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-2.0

I have a Spark RDD whose entries I want to sort in an organized manner. Let's say the entry is a tuple with 3 elements `(name,phonenumber,timestamp)`. I want to sort the entries first depending on the value of `phonenumber` and then depending on the value of `timestamp` while respecting and not changing the sort that was done based on `phonenumber`. (so `timestamp` only re-arranges based on the `phonenumber` sort). Is there a Spark function to do this?

(I am using Spark 2.x with Scala)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to do the sorting based on Multiple elements in RDD, you can use `sortBy` function. Please find below some sample code in Python. you can similarly implement in other languages as well.

```
tmp = [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('1', 3), ('1', 4), ('2', 5)]

sc.parallelize(tmp).sortBy(lambda x: (x[0], x[1]), False).collect()
```

Regards,

Neeraj

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sortBy` function on `RDD` as below

```
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  ("a","1", "2017-03-10"),
  ("b","12", "2017-03-9"),
  ("b","123", "2015-03-12"),
  ("c","1234", "2015-03-15"),
  ("c","12345", "2015-03-12")
))//.toDF("name", "phonenumber", "timestamp")

df.sortBy(x => (x._1, x._3)).foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
(c,1234,2015-03-15)
(c,12345,2015-03-12)
(b,12,2017-03-9)
(b,123,2015-03-12)
(a,1,2017-03-10)
```

If you have a dataframe with `toDF("name", "phonenumber", "timestamp")`
Then you could simply do

```
df.sort("name", "timestamp")
```

Hope this helps!